# Cannot Read Property 'getSheetId' of null; Not sure why this happens

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a the following snippet of code

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var driverArray = sheet.getRange("H2:H33").getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!="");
 
 var ssname = ss.getName();
 var length = ssname.length;
 var shName = sheet.getName();
 var date = ssname.substring(0,length-15);
 var scheduleDate = ss.getSheets()[7].getRange("G27").getValue(); //this contains a formula, but it evaluates to a date coinciding with the title of a sheet
 const body = "Hello, <br><br>Attached is the pay stub for the week ending "+ date+"."+"<br><br> Thank you, <br> Elizabeth";
 var arrayLength = driverArray.length;
 
  var scheduleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetURL");
  var scheduleSS = scheduleSheet.getId();
  var nextSchedule = scheduleSheet.getSheetByName(scheduleDate);
  var scheduleID  = nextSchedule.getSheetId(); // I believe the error is coming here
```

I am trying to get the ID of a sheet on a different spreadsheet. I believe that I am navigating to that sheet correctly, but I get the error "cannot read property of 'getSheetId' of null". Does this mean that it did not find a sheet with the name?

G27 contains the formula

```
=(Leftb(Summary!$A$2,2)&"-"&Midb(Summary!$A$2,3,2)&"-"&rightb(Summary!$A$2,2))+7
```

but it evaluates to a date. And the format of the date matches correctly with the title of the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
var scheduleDate = ss.getSheets()[7].getRange("G27").getValue()
```

use

```
var scheduleDate = ss.getSheets()[7].getRange("G27").getDisplayValue()
```

The above because `getValue()` returns a Date object for cells holding a date value and usually the Date object is parsed as string in a long format rather than the usual date formats.